$\{f \geq y \} = f^{-1}((- \infty, x^*)) $ not $\{f \geq y \} = (- \infty, x^*)$?
I was reading the solution of the following question here Monotone functions are Borel-measurable :
Every monotone function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Borel-measurable.
Here is the solution given there:
Via definition of Borel-measurability, it suffices to show, that $$\forall y \in \mathbb{R}: \{f \geq y\} \in \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R}). $$
Proof:
Let wlog $f$ be a non-increasing function and $y \in \mathbb{R}$ fix.
(1)  If $\{f \geq y \}  = \emptyset$ than $\{f \geq y \} \in \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R}) $
(2) If $\{f \geq y \}  \neq \emptyset $ define $x^* :=\sup\{x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) \geq y \} $. Than we have:

$x^* = \infty \Rightarrow \{ f \geq y \} = \mathbb{R} \in \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R}) $

$x^* < \infty$:

$x^* \in \{ f \geq y \} \Rightarrow \{f \geq y \} = (- \infty, x^*] \in \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R}) $
$x^* \notin \{ f \geq y \} \Rightarrow \{f \geq y \} = (- \infty, x^*) \in \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R}) $



Since all these sets are in $\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$ arbitrary $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is measurable.
My questions are:
In the two lines before last, should not the equality be with the preimage of the set not the set itself i.e., I mean $$\{f \geq y \} = f^{-1}((- \infty, x^*)) $$ not $$\{f \geq y \} = (- \infty, x^*)$$ and same for the other equality?
If I am wrong, can any one explain this to me please?

By definition,
$$\{f\ge y\} =\{x\in\mathbb R : f(x)\ge y \} = \{x\in\mathbb R : f(x)\in [y,+\infty) \} =f^{-1}([y,+\infty))  $$
Now, because $f$ is non-increasing, we have $x_1\ge x_2\implies f(x_1)\le f(x_2)$, so indeed, if $x^*\in \{f\ge y\}$, we have that $x\in\{f\ge y\}$ if and only if $x\le x^*$, i.e.
$$ \{f\ge y\} = (-\infty,x^*]. $$
And similarly, if $x^*\in\mathbb R\setminus\{f\ge y\}$, we have by definition of the supremum that $x\in\{f\ge y\}$ if and only if $x< x^*$, i.e.
$$ \{f\ge y\} = (-\infty,x^*), $$
hopefully that clears it up.
